# Spark infer schema and use it load data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I want to infer the schema from a large dataset(say 6 months data) and use it to load smaller data sets(hourly).

How can I infer the schema and save it to a file and use the saved schema to load the data?

I have learned to store the schema to a file from 
[How to write a DataFrame schema to file in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137741/how-to-write-a-dataframe-schema-to-file-in-scala)

How can I use the same schema stored in the file to load another dataset? TO summarize
1) Load the data for a larger time period so that I will capture all the available fields
2) Store the inferred schema to file (One-time activity)
3) Use the stored schema to load smaller datasets

Comment: Did you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957585/create-spark-dataframe-schema-from-json-schema-representation/40957586